# Is it possible to limit targets of NSNotification?

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsnotifications, nsnotificationcenter

I want to send a NSNotification to a specific object (to self), without having other objects see / respond to it.

Is this possible without editing the other objects?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use a unique notification name for this particular notification? (and then have this object be the only one observing it)

Comment: There is.  Getting into it is pointless, but essentially the class is subclassed, and the subclasses can have multiple notifications from other objects using the same standard notification name.  Otherwise, each subclass has to respond to standard notification, and each of their own unique notification sent by the superclass (which the superclass has to somehow know about - poor programming.)  I want the superclass to send to itself (one of the instantiated subclasses) a notification without others responding to it.

Comment: I see. And there is sometimes more than one instance of a given subclass? (Not sure I have an answer, just documenting the constraints for anyone else reading this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you really must use the same notification name, one thought would be to put the self pointer into userInfo. Then on the observer side, if you don't see a self pointer then you assume it's a general notification, not specific to any particular observer.

If you **do** see a self pointer, you compare it to yourself to decide if to handle it. I'm not sure it satisfies your constraint of "no edits", but it does at least satisfy the requirement that the superclass code doesn't need to know of all the possible subclasses.

Comment: I've considered that, but it requires editing all of the subclasses and remembering to check for that target pointer.  Not optimum.